# private variables in my class aren't working c++

Tags: c++, class, debugging

My outputs for the BR and DR member functions just give me zeros. I'm guessing I'm either not assigning the private members correctly or not using them correctly. I know there are easier ways to do this without classes but alas this was how my prof wants it done. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Population 
{
private:
//private variables
int births, deaths, population; 
public: 
//Member functons
void setpop(int); //sets population value
void setB(int); //sets birth value
void setD(int); //sets death value
double BR() const; //calculates birth-rate
double DR() const; //calculates death-rate
};
void Population::setpop(int p)
{
population = p; //assigns local variable from before to private member        
}

void Population::setB(int b)
{
births = b; //assigns local variable from before to private member in class
}

void Population::setD(int d)
{
deaths = d; //assigns local variable from before to private member in class
}

double Population::BR() const
{
cout<<endl;
return births/population; //birth-rate
}
double Population::DR() const
{
cout<<endl;
return deaths/population; //death-rate
}

int main()
{
int localpopulation, localbirths, localdeaths; //local as in local variable
cout<<"Birth-Rate and Death-Rate program: "<<endl;
cout<<"Enter the population: ";
cin>>localpopulation;
//if statements to make sure the values qualify
if (localpopulation<1)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid population. Try again: ";
        cin>>localpopulation;
    }
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Enter the number of births: ";
cin>>localbirths;
if (localbirths<0)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid births. Try again: ";
        cin>>localbirths;
    }
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Enter deaths: ";
cin>>localdeaths;
if (localdeaths<0)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid deaths. Try again: ";
        cin>>localdeaths;
    }
Population object;
object.setpop(localpopulation);
object.setB(localbirths);
object.setD(localdeaths);
cout<<endl;
cout<<"The Birth-Rate is: "<<fixed<< setprecision(2)<<object.BR();
cout<<endl;
cout<<"The Death-Rate is: "<<fixed<< setprecision(2)<<object.DR();

}
```

Example output from this code:

Birth-Rate and Death-Rate program: 
Enter the population: 1000

Enter the number of births: 30

Enter deaths: 20

The Birth-Rate is: 0.00

The Death-Rate is: 0.00

Comment: BTW you are performing an integer division so the result is also an integer. So 30/1000 is 0 when performing integer division. You probably need to use an explicit cast here.

Comment: Should `births`. `deaths` be unsigned. Also can the population just be calculated - i.e. `births - deaths`

Comment: Indentation, people. *Indentation!*

Comment: Perhaps `BR` should be `birthRate` - Stops people trying to guess in future and "BR" was privatized my John Major

Comment: Didn't know John Major was involved in HTML.

Comment: `<br>` - An [empty tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) - So I guess this is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is the variables for births and deaths are integers so you when using those methods integer division will happen. Thus the floating point part of the result will be truncated.

**So you will always see zero until you enter something where births is greater than population**

You could change these variables to double or float type so integer division does not take place or a better way to fix this is just cast the values before performing and kind of division.

**The return statements in each method will look like:**

```
return births/double(population);
```

**And**

```
return deaths/double(population);
```

Comment: Changing births to floats is not a good idea. How does a half a birth occur? For that matter what is half a death?

Comment: Well birth rate and death rate are percentages thus they will produce floats. I see what you are saying what is your suggestion then?

Comment: Keep births and deaths as unsigned integers. Do the conversion to floats/doubles to compute the rate.

Comment: @EdHeal you really need to see The Princess Bride to get floating point death.

Comment: I switched the private members to doubles and the parameters to the functions accordingly. It works now. Thanks for the input guys!

Comment: @Matthew Cabrera Not a good idea to to do that...see the comment by Ed Heal.

Comment: You can do that but it is a probably better to use my second method in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Like sebenalem noted, C++ utilizes different functionality for different types.

```
cout << double(1 / 2) << endl;
// Output: 0.0
```

C++ also has a feature called typecasting, where you are allowed to change a value's type on the fly to instruct different things. An example of typecasting:

```
cout << 1 / double(2) << endl;
// Output: 0.5
```

The latter example casts the 2 into a double (2.0) before the division is evaluated; C++ then sees this evaluation as '1 / 2.0' instead of '1 / 2', converting the evaluation to **floating-point division** instead of **integer division**.

The reason your values are truncating is that you're typecasting the entire division's result into a double, and you're not using floating-point division properly.

Here are some nice reads when you have the time:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-4a-explicit-type-conversion-casting/
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-implicit-type-conversion-coercion/

Comment: Thanks for the info!